# i have send 2 generic args for funion first one is char and second is int why the first if cond is work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have send two generic args to func and simple ask if they are typeof int and i send one of them as a char and second one as a int but still the if cindison is work exsample : and the result is the first if cond is work and i dont realy undestand why because the first arg is char

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {

        public static T Adds<T>(T number1 , T number2 )
        {
            if ((number1 is int) && (number2 is int))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("int test");
            }
            else if (number1 is double )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("double test");
            }
            return number1;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Adds('c',2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `char` can be *implicitly* converted into `int` (`char` is, in fact, `UInt16` when `int` is `Int32`), `Add<T>(T number1, T number2)` can well be executed as `Add<int>((int) 'c', 2);` Another demonstration: `Add(7, 5.3)` is equal to `Add<double>((double) 7, 5.3)`

Comment: so what can i do if i realy want to check it for only int ?

Comment: If you want to *separate* arguments types: put it like  `public static T1 Adds<T1, T2>(T1 number1 , T2 number2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current signature

```
 T Adds<T>(T number1, T number2)
```

ensures that *both* arguments `number1` and `number2` must be of the *same* type. That's why

```
 Add('c', 2)
 Add(1, 3.14)
```

will be executed as

```
 Add<int>((int)'c', 2);
 Add<double>((double)1, 3.14);
```

since `char` can be *converted implicitly* into `int` and (2nd example) `int` can be  *converted implicitly* into `double`. If you want to treat each parameter with its own type try

```
// T1 Adds<T1, T2>: if Adds return 1st parameter
// T2 Adds<T1, T2>: if Adds return 2nd parameter 
T1 Adds<T1, T2>(T1 number1, T2 number2) {
  ...
}
```

In this case

```
Add('c', 2)
```

will be called as

```
// No conversion: T1 is char, T2 is int
Add<char, int>('c', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
class Program
{
    public static T Adds<T>(object number1, object number2)
    {
        if ((number1 is int) && (number2 is int))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("int test");
        }
        else if (number1 is double)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("double test");
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(number1, typeof(T));
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Adds<int>('c', 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all tnx for the fast answer second of all i want to send 2 T args the function Not an object .. and still if i send it with Console.WriteLine(Adds<int>('c', 2)); i get the same wird solution .. i semply want to check it for 2 args because if i do it for 1 arg the fun is work find it is all mass up if i send to type if T can u tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the method with a single generic type. If you wish for the arguments to have separate types, you must declare

```
public static T Adds<T,T2>(T number1 , T2 number2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told the compiler which type to use for T. 
Number1 and Number2 must have the same type. 
As a char is implicitly castable to int, the type int is used.

If you debug your code you will see that number1 is of type int with the value 99.

If you would try to call:

```
Console.WriteLine(Adds<char>('c',2));
```

there would be a compile error raised.

Answer (score 0):

this because compiler implicitly cast it to int to be both of parameters int

if you try to specify T Type explicitly like following you will get compilation error

```
 Console.WriteLine(Adds<char>('c',2));
```

because both of parameters can't be implicitly casted to char
and to overcome this issue you need to cast second parmaeter to char

```
Console.WriteLine(Adds<char>('c',(char)2));
```

this is reference of [Implicit Numeric Conversions Table (C# Reference)][1]

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table it will help also